# Como se puede hacer un bot para discord que no use comandos en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.7, discord.py

he hecho un bot de discord que usa comandos pero lo que quiero es que el bot escriba automaticamente un link en un canal de mi servidor de discord pero no puedo lograr hacer eso sin usar los comandos, he intentado muchas cosas y nada, he buscado tutoriales y nadie me dice nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué no lees el código fuente de la librería de comandos de discord? Es probable que estén usando el API de discord y comunicándose con el usando la librería requests.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El bot necesita que le indiques cuando quieres que envíe el mensaje. Para ello, lo más habitual es usar comandos. Sin embargo, hay 2  alternativas:

**[Eventos](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference):** Puedes redefinir algún evento para que se manden los enlaces cuando se llame a un evento. Una posibilidad sería  [`on_ready()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_ready), al que se llama cuando se lanza el bot. De esta manera, el bot mandaría los enlaces al conectarse:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='x',intents=discord.Intents.default())

guild_id = 123456789
channel_id = 987654321

def scrapper():
    # Todo lo relacionado con requests y bs4
    return ["link de prueba 1", "link de prueba 2"] # los links que quieras enviar

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    # Obtener el canal por el que mandar el mensaje
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
    # Obtener los links (contenido que tendrá el mensaje)
    links = scrapper()
    # Mandar el mensaje por el canal
    await channel.send("\n".join(links))
    print("Conectado")

bot.run("Tu Token")
```

---

---

**[Tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#):** La otra alternativa es enviar periódicamente los enlaces haciendo uso del decorador [tasks.loop()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.loop). El bot enviará los enlaces cada cierto tiempo (el que se le indique). No olvides añadir [tasks.Loop.start()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.start) en el cuerpo de la función `on_ready()`:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='x',intents=discord.Intents.default())

guild_id = 123456789
channel_id = 987654321
# Guardamos ahora como variables globales el canal
channel = None

def scrapper():
    # Todo lo relacionado con requests y bs4
    return ["link de prueba 1", "link de prueba 2"] # los links que quieras enviar

@tasks.loop(seconds = 60) # se ejecutará esta función cada 60 segundos
async def enviar_links():
    # Obtener los links en cada iteración, suponiendo que puedan cambiar...
    links = scrapper()
    await channel.send("\n".join(links))

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global channel
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
    # Empezamos el bucle en el que se ejecutará la tarea
    enviar_links.start()
    print("Conectado")

bot.run("Tu Token")
```

Nótese que como ahora no hay [`context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20context#discord.ext.commands.Context), hay que indicar manualmente el canal por el que se deben mandar los enlaces. Puedes obtener el canal en el evento `on_ready()` tal como se ve en ambos ejemplos.